# Supporting previous versions of iOS - where used third party library has target of higher version

Tags: ios

You are doing iOS development and for a particular task (for example: push notification, or handling connection)
you are using a third part library. But this lib is supporting from a specific version(for example: iOS 8.0). But you want to provide support for previous versions as well, as your users might have previous iOS version installed in their devices.

How to provide a generic solution for this kind of scenario?

Comment: [Pods](https://cocoapods.org/)  will take care.

Comment: if a 3rd party stuff supports iOS _n_, then your project which uses it must support minimum iOS _n_ too; you cannot support iOS _n-1_ it does not matter ho much you'd like to... the generic solution is that you just stop using 3rd party libraries and make your project dependent on your code-base only, and you can have more control on such situations.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to indicate support for older iOS versions. Within XCode, select your project item then the main app target. In General tab, select the minimum iOS version you want to support as Deployment Target.

By doing this, the compiler will add MinimumOSVersion value to your app’s info.plist file during one of the build phrase. The value is used by both iTunes AppStore and iOS.

[image]

Certainly when targeting older iOS versions, you should be careful on using APIs recently introduced or deprecating. It is best practice to check for OS version or test if the object are responding to a selector to handle API differences gracefully.

Be aware that Deployment Target is different from Base SDK in project setting. Base SDK specifies version of static library you want to build/link with at compile time.